# Unable to update entity asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have an object which is returned from one controller to another (GET) and then the form is changed by the user, and when I try to POST, the changes to the object isn't saved.

The constructor of the class has an instance of the context (which is injected).

```
var testObject = _context.TestClass.Find(testView.Id);
```

This gives the object I would like to edit.

```
testObject.Name = "new name";
```

When I then use _context.SaveChanges();

Everything reverts back to the previous state.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was rather optimistic when adding. I had a viewModel which has the entity as an object, I thought it should be fine to write testObject = viewModel.testObject. I had to define all attributes manually, or use automapper.